# VBA - Copy Cell and Paste Down Blank Rows in Column

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a template for others to paste their data into the file, and for a macro to run and copy formulas down all rows that contain data.  The sheet contains headers.  The formula is in column D (Price). I want the macro to start in cell D2, and copy the formula in cell D2 down all rows in column D.

[image: Example file]

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself - this is a common question?

Comment: Yes, I have looked.  I know nothing about VBA.  I've tried multiple solutions that get me close.  You saying it's a common question without pointing me to valid solution is not helpful.

Comment: Dave, SJR's is a valid remark on this site. You might want to review the guidelines about asking questions here in the [help]. SO targets answering programmer's questions about code they're having problems with. It's not a code-writing service or a tutorial site - We're not here to write code for those who ask questions, but to help them solve any problems they encounter. You need to show effort. For example, use the [edit] link to add the code that comes closest to what you need and describe *how* it "doesn't work". But in order to understand answers some knowledge of VBA would be useful...

Comment: Also, in order to answer someone in comments ("ping" them - put a message in their inbox) you need to precede their name with a `@`, for example: @DaveT.

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error, and mashing up different recommendations, this is what works for my purposes:

Public Sub CopyDownRows()

Dim rng As Range
Dim LR As Long

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("D3:D" & LR)
Range("D").Select
Selection.Copy
rng.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

End Sub

Comment: Using *select* is a lazy way of programming.
https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/how-to-avoid-the-select-method/